# PlayFramework: How to safely integrate Bootstrap theme with Require.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, requirejs, playframework-2.1

In Playframework 2.1 - Asycronous Module Definition (AMD) was introduced & supported with Require.js

Yet there is a lack of official Play Documentation besides the overview:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/RequireJS-support

I am looking to put together a tutorial on the best practices of supporting Bootstrap themes with Require.js

The code base for bootstrap, jquery spans across multiple files:

```
jquery.js 
      jquery.dataTable.js
      jquery-ui.custom.js
      ...
bootstrap.js
      bootstrap.colorpicker.js
      bootstrap.tooltip.js
      ...
Over 30 of these Bootstrap themed files needs to be managed.
```

In `app/assets/js`, I have:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "assets/javascripts/lib",
    paths: {
        "jquery": ["http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min",
            //If the CDN location fails, load from this location
            'jquery-1.10.1.min'
        ],
        "bootstrap" : ['bootstrap.min'],

    },
    shim : {
        "bootstrap" : ['jquery'],
        "jquery.dataTables" : ['jquery'],
        "jquery-ui.custom" : ['jquery'],
        'jquery.uniform' : ['jquery'],
        'excanvas' : ['jquery'],
        'jquery.flot.min' : ['jquery'],
        'jquery.flot.resize.min' : ['jquery'],
        'jquery.peity.min' : ['jquery'],
        'select2' : ['jquery'],
        'unicorn' : ['jquery', 'bootstrap'],
        'unicorn.dashboard' : ['jquery', 'bootstrap'],
        'unicorn.tables' : ['jquery', 'bootstrap']
    }
});
```

In `project/Build.scala`, the requireJs is appended to main:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    requireJs += "main.js",
    requireJsShim += "main.js",
    requireJsFolder := "js"
)
```

In my template, `app/views/main.scala.html`, the helper is invoked:

```
@helper.requireJs(core = routes.Assets.at("javascripts/require.js").url, module = routes.Assets.at("js/main").url)
```

I have many template pages that routes from main.scala.html, right now the helper gets called once per page. Therefore I'm running into **baseUrl** errors:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/admin/assets/javascripts/lib/bootstrap.min.js 404 (Not Found) require.js:33
GET http://localhost:9000/admin/assets/javascripts/lib/jquery.dataTables.js 404 (Not Found) require.js:33
GET http://localhost:9000/admin/assets/javascripts/lib/jquery.uniform.js 404 (Not Found) require.js:33
GET http://localhost:9000/admin/assets/javascripts/lib/jquery-ui.custom.js 404 (Not Found) require.js:33
GET http://localhost:9000/admin/assets/javascripts/lib/select2.js 404 (Not Found) require.js:33
GET http://localhost:9000/admin/assets/javascripts/lib/excanvas.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Is there a best practice for safely integrating Boostrap in PlayFramework with Require.js?

Comment: That shim config doesn't look right to me. I don't think you pass arrays to it. Read the docs - http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim. Can you also confirm the location of all your JS files?

Comment: The shim config array is right. http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim
If the deps are just jQuery or Bootstrap. 
Most of my JS library files are in public/javascripts/lib

Comment: Ah yes you're right. Where would you expect to find the JS files if you browsed to them directly? `/public/javascripts/lib/bootstrap.min.js` for example?

Comment: I'm using the controller to browse to them @routes.Assets.at("javascripts/lib/bootstrap.min.js")

Comment: Forgot to mention in my conf->routes:
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)

Answer (score 0):

As of May 1st, 2013 - Christopher Hunt who works on the Play Framework team is making Javascript integration better: 
http://christopherhunt-software.blogspot.com/

Also check out WebJARS - http://www.webjars.org/